# MAUI: Lock Flyout menu while running activity indicator

Tags: maui, flyout

how can I lock the flyout menu when an activity indicator is currently running. I want, if there is a calculation on a page, to lock the menu, so that the user has to wait until the calculation is finished. In this time, when I display a running activity indicator, the user should have no possibility to open the menu or to change the page.

How can this be done?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could use **FlyoutBehavior** property. There are three values for **FlyoutBehavior** : *Disabled*, *Flyout* and *Locked*. So we could disable the flyout if we set **FlyoutBehavior** to *Disabled*.

When doing the calculation, set the **this.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Disabled** and when the calculation is finished, set **this.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Flyout**. You could use MessagingCenter to notify.

In the FlyoutPage, create a subscriber to receive message

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CalculationPage, string>(this, "Hi", (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args == "Enable")
        {
            this.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Flyout;
        }
        else if (args == "Disable")
        {
            this.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Disabled;
        }
    });


}
```

And in the calculation page, when you start calculation:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<CalculationPage,string>(this, "Hi","Disable");
```

when calculation is finished, set it back:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<CalculationPage, string>(this, "Hi", "Enable");
```

For more information about MessagingCenter, you could refer to [Publish and subscribe to messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0)

Hope my answer could help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a Flyout page. I build my flyout menu in the AppShell with some ShellContents and the page displayed is a ContentPage. In the ContentPage i do not have the IsGestureEnabled property :(

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. To use `this.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Disabled`, we disable the flyout menu.

Comment: This also not worked for me. But in the ContentPage itself I can use Shell.Current.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Disabled; Thank you!